# What goes wrong in this proof that the sum of zero divisors is a zero divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

There are many counterexamples to the claim that the sum of two zero divisors is a zero divisor; see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628673/should-the-sum-of-zero-divisors-also-a-zero-divisor). However, I do not understand why the following "proof" fails:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $a, b \in R$ be two zero divisors, i.e. there are $k \ne 0$ and $l \ne 0$ such that $ak = 0$ and $bl = 0$. Since $kl \cdot (a+b) = akl + bkl = 0 + 0 = 0$ we see that $a+b$ is also a zero divisor.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps $kl$ is $0$?

Comment: @lulu: Ah, thank you, I got it now.

Comment: (or if one wanted to leave something to be figured out) Actually $xy=0$ does not imply that $y$ is a zero divisor.